# Assigning list in freemarker template

Tags: json, freemarker

I want to create a json from a freemarker template.

My output json

```
{
  data : ["123", "234", "346"]
}
```

So I have a list inputData: ["123", "234", "346"].
I want to do something like below in .ftl template.

```
<#escape x as x?json_string>
{
   "data": "${inputData}"
}
</#escape>
```

But getting the below error

```
content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, FreeMarker isn't specialized to dump data into JSON format, so there's the manual approach:

```
{
   "data": [<#list inputData as i>"${i?json_string}"<#sep>, </#list>]
}
```

Of course if you do these a lot, then it worth writing some `#macro`-s or such for it.

Comment: <#sep> syntax throws error. I know I can write something like you suggested but there is trailing , which is the problem, example["123", "234", "346" , ]

Comment: The error  may be because I am using version 2.3.20 of freemarker